# How to see/change learning rate in Keras LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm, learning-rate

I see in some question/answers that ask to decrease the learning rate. But I don't know how can I see and change the learning rate of `LSTM` model in `Keras` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Keras, you can set the learning rate as a parameter for the optimization method, the piece of code below is an example from Keras documentation:

```
    from keras import optimizers

   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='uniform', input_shape=(10,)))
   model.add(Activation('softmax'))

   sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
   model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
```

In the above code, the fifth line `lr` is learning rate, which in this code is set to 0.01. You change it to whatever you want.

For further detail, see this [link](https://keras.io/optimizers/).

Please tell me if this helped to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much honar. I will test it as soon as possible and tell you about the result.

Comment: I was using `Adam` optimizer, so I added these two line of the code and seems it works. 
`from Keras import optimizers`
`optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)`

Comment: Do you know how can I see the value of `learning rate` during the training? I use `Adam` optimizer.

Comment: as I know, the learning rate in your case does not change and remains 0.0001.

Comment: Yes, I put the wrong code, I meant I like to see if I change decay value how will it change the learning rate value during the training process?